# How to perform html minify with Revel framework

Tags: go, revel

My first idea was to get the response body within the filter, then use one of minify libraries like tdewolff/minify and write to response, but i cant find the way to get response body.
Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, by looking at the docs, that a filter can access the `Controller` type, which contains the `Response`. This response contains `Out` which is a ResponseWriter (and thus also an io.Writer). We need to replace only the Write method to redirect the write to the minifier, which then writes to the response writer. We need to use `io.Pipe` and a goroutine for this.

```
type MinifyResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    io.Writer
}

func (f MinifyResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return f.Writer.Write(b)
}

func MinifyFilter(c *Controller, fc []Filter) {
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    go func(w io.Writer) {
        m := minify.New()
        m.AddFunc("text/css", css.Minify)
        m.AddFunc("text/html", html.Minify)
        m.AddFunc("text/javascript", js.Minify)
        m.AddFunc("image/svg+xml", svg.Minify)
        m.AddFuncRegexp(regexp.MustCompile("[/+]json$"), json.Minify)
        m.AddFuncRegexp(regexp.MustCompile("[/+]xml$"), xml.Minify)

        if err := m.Minify("mimetype", w, pr); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }(c.Response.Out)
    c.Response.Out = MinifyResponseWriter{c.Response.Out, pw}
}
```

Something along those lines (not tested). Here we take the incoming `io.Writer` (which is part of the `ResponseWriter`), and wrap a struct around that. It keeps the original methods for the response writer, but the Write method is overrided to be replaced by the `PipeWriter`. This means that any write to the new response writer goes to `PipeWriter`, which is coupled to `PipeReader`. Minify Reads from that reader and writes to the original response writer.

Because we change the value of `c.Response.Out`, we need to pass it explicitly to the goroutine. Make sure you obtain the correct mimetype (through extension?) or call the appropriate minify function directly.

Comment: its working in Firefox, but Chrome doesnt display page with error net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH. Tried to insert filter before or after revel.CompressFilter with no success.

Comment: I'm not sure how Revel works, but take a look at https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/master/compress.go#L46, it seems that you need to remove the content-length header so it gets recalculated?

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help and nice minify library) The only problem i see is endless errors like goroutine 45 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Syncsemacquire(0xc82013aa00) ; /home/venom/gocode/src/github.com/tdewolff/buffer/shifter.go:75 after i renew page like 10 times

Comment: Thanks! That is a weird error, by the line number it seems to come from the Read function of the given io.Reader. Maybe because the pipe isn't properly closed? Can't say for sure without more information.

Comment: 111 line is: if err := m.Minify("text/html", w, pr); err != nil { panic(err)} Error: Conn.Write wrote more than the declared Content-Length; goroutine 56 [running]:
my-site/app.glob.func3.1(0xc820281810, 0xc820276b28, 0x7f834fdb4100, 0xc820281760)
 /home/venom/gocode/src/my-site/app/init.go:111 +0x666
created by my-site/app.glob.func3
 /home/venom/gocode/src/my-site/app/init.go:114 +0x2f4

Comment: Can't say what is going on without more information. Please identify whether this is a bug in Minify or not.

Comment: This error (Conn.Write wrote more than the declared Content-Length) appers randomly (from 2 page renews to 30). I think it happens for some strange reason when new content length of minified content is countent, but non-minified version is written to response, so actual size of content is bigger than expexted content length. Additionally, this error occurs randomly, so I think its just easier to minify html by text editor rather than solve this problem:(

Comment: Sounds like a data race (check with `go test -race`) or something. But if you want to compress it in the text editor this tool will help: http://pi.tacodewolff.nl:8080/minify